# The code below is showing error of invalid identifier in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, identifier

```
create table productinfotwo
(
productId number(10),
CONSTRAINT primary_pk Primary Key(productId),
productname varchar2(100),
SUBCATEGORYID number(10),
CONSTRAINT subcategory_fk Foreign Key(SUBCATEGORYID ) REFERENCES ProductSubCategory(SUBCATEGORYID ), 
COMPANYID varchar2(20), 
CONSTRAINT company_fk Foreign Key(COMPANYID ) References CompanyInfo(COMPANYID ),
price float,
quantity number(10),
description varchar2(1000),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have them in order

1. Create ProductSubCategory table
2. Create CompanyInfo table
3. There is no datatype called float in Oracle. You can use NUMBER(4,2) instead
4. Remove the comma after description

The code should be

```
CREATE TABLE productinfotwo 
  ( 
     productid     NUMBER(10), 
          CONSTRAINT primary_pk PRIMARY KEY(productid), 
          productname   VARCHAR2(100), 
          subcategoryid NUMBER(10), 
          CONSTRAINT subcategory_fk FOREIGN KEY(subcategoryid ) REFERENCES 
          productsubcategory(subcategoryid ), 
          companyid     VARCHAR2(20), 
          CONSTRAINT company_fk FOREIGN KEY(companyid ) REFERENCES companyinfo( 
          companyid ), 
     price         NUMBER(4, 2), 
     quantity      NUMBER(10), 
     description   VARCHAR2(1000) 
  );
```

Comment: Good answer but I wouldn't recommend `number(4,2)` for a price.

Comment: Yup, I agree its just to save him for time being. We never know what OP is upto